# Itext7 modify table width

Tags: itext7

In java itext5 there is function table.setWidths() hence we can modify column widths on fly.
In itext7 table.setWidths() is not there and  new Table(colwidths) have to pass in constructor this is fixed and cannot modyify on fly.Please let me know the procedure to modify table widths like itext5.

```
Itext5
Table table = new Table(3);
float[] widths=new float[3.0,4.0,5.0];
table.setWidths(widths);
```

what is the above code itext7?

Comment: You can always create a new table if you need to set different column widths

Comment: I can create new table.But widths i got based on string width after navigating all rows.I need to set widths in existing table or i have to copy data from one table to another new table.

Comment: You can save your cells into a temporary data structure, do all the necessary calculations and then create a table based on that data